# naudio waveform fit to waveviewer

Tags: c#, naudio

Is there any possibility to fit the whole waveform of an audio file to waveviewer?
I mean if wave file 1 would lasts for 2 seconds or wave file 2 for 15 seconds they will be fitted to the waveviewer.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking.  The longer (in elapsed time) that a waveform is, the more screen "real-estate" required to display the waveform at a given resolution (or zoom-level).  You can render the points of a 1-hour long waveform on the same screen as you would a 2-second long waveform, but visually they will look very different because the 1-hour waveform needs to be extremely zoomed-out to show the entire waveform.

Comment: I meant that I wanted to visualise waveforms of my audio files so that, for example, kick drum will be fitted to the waveviewer. On the other hand some guitar riff is not displaying as whole waveform but only a part of it so I want to fit it too. And I dont care about visuals, I want to only display the whole waveform of a file.

Answer (score 0):

The nAudio `WaveViewer` class / control has a property called `SamplesPerPixel` which will effectively provide different 'zoom-levels' to the rendering of your output.

So, for example if your guitar riff is 15 seconds long at a 44.1K sample rate, then it contains 661,500 samples.

If you want to make sure that this entire waveform is shown in a `WaveViewer` instance that has a width of 800 pixels then you'd want the `SamplesPerPixel` setting to be around 800 - 850.